# Using iOS Magnifying Glass for HTML table?

Tags: html, ios, css

I have an HTML page with mark up as follows:

```
<h2>Lorem Lorem Ip Ip Sum</h2>
<p>yup yup yup<p/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Side</td>
        <td>Role</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Obi Wan Kenobi</td>
        <td>Light</td>
        <td>Jedi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Greedo</td>
        <td>South</td>
        <td>Scumbag</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When viewed on an iPhone, if you hold your finger down on the h2 or 'p" tags you get the iOS magnifying glass that zooms the copy, but if you hold down your finger on the table elements it just highlights the content. Is it possible to get the magnifying glass on the table elements?

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-user-select: auto;`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried none,auto, and text. Each just effected the selectability but not the zoomability.